# Highcharts: Add arrows at the end of X/Y axis

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular-highcharts

I'm trying to add arrow at the end of X and Y axis like in the following image

[image: arrow at the end of X and Y axis]

using the following [answer](https://github.com/hcharts/highcharts-axis-arrow/blob/master/highcharts-axis-arrow.js), But angular gives me "Property does not exist error" for few of the properties.

I'm unable to find a solution for the problem

[image: Error: Property does not exist on type]

Comment: Hi @Kedar Udupa, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor? I see that you are using different code than here: http://jsfiddle.net/z2aagpeu/ You can start from: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek I have updated my question (had posted a wrong link!). I could not reproduce in online editor. It could be from my editor. I ended up adding 'any' type as aquick fix. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the info! Please try to type `this` in the function. Example: `axisProto.renderLine = function(this: Highcharts.Axis){...}`